# Infinite redirection in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I am implementing AngularJS for redirection in Codeigniter project but it's cause infinite redirection. My Directory and file structure is as under:

```
    application
        controllers
            admin
                home.php
        view
            admin
                home
                    index.php
                listing
                    index.php
                theme
                    header.php
                    footer.php
                    index.php
    system
```

***AngularJS CODE:***

**Header.php**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);


    sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $routeProvider.
                when('/angular/ci/admin/home/', {
                    templateUrl: 'home'
                }).
                when('/angular/ci/admin/home/listing/', {
                    templateUrl: 'home/listing'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/angular/ci/admin/home/'
                });
        }
    ]);
</script>

<div>header</div>

<div>
    <a href="http://localhost/angular/ci/admin/home/">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="http://localhost/angular/ci/admin/home/listing/">Listing</a>
</div>
```

**theme/index.php**

```
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
    <?php
        $this->load->view(ADMIN_THEME."header.php");
    ?>
    <div class='ng-view'>
        <?php
            $this->load->view('admin/'.$pagename);            
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        $this->load->view(ADMIN_THEME."footer.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

**controllers/home.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $data['pagename']='home/index';
        $this->load->view(ADMIN_THEME.'index',$data);
    }
    public function listing(){
        //echo 'hi';
        $this->load->view('admin/listing');

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file that is causing a redirect when a file is not found? I have had an issue using that where if any file is not found it redirects to the document root and then repeats until the browser crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirectTo a path that is defined.

in other words, when you redirect to '/', it goes through the paths and looks for a match, and since one is not found, it redirects to '/', etc.  You should redirect to /angular/ci/admin/home/ or /angular/ci/admin/home/listing/

good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but i also try that. Right now it's working but i am facing issue with infinite, because of my theme(header,footer etc). When i am click on link it will option related page but it also load all the theme files and that's why it goes in infinite. Please can  you help me, how to stop this infinite redirection?

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure, but it sounds like it's considering the header/footer loading as a client-side redirect.  In that case, you might try NOT using HTML5 mode and prefixing the client-side links with '#'.  Also, I don't think there should be anything being loaded in the 'ng-view' directive.  THat's managed by the angular router, if I'm not mistaken.